# Show posts from a specific category - Wordpress

Tags: php, post

I am having an issue where by I need to show only specific posts on my home from a certain category otherwise it is showing anything and everything that is posted and I am using posts around the site for other purposes.

```
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=3'); while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 

   <span style="float: left; width: 180px; height: 180px; padding: 0px 60px 0px 0px;"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array(220,200) ); ?>   </span>                  

    <h3 class="excerptHeader" style="margin-top: 0px;"><a class="excerptHeader" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

     <span class="excerpt"><p><?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,80); ?> [...]</p></span>

      <span class="excerpt"><p><a class="excerptLink" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read full article</a></p></span>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I have tried adding in:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query arguments as follows:

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=3&cat=nn')
```

Where `nn` is the `ID` of the category you wish to select posts from.

Check [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) page for more details.

Comment: so just change nn to the name of my category?

Comment: How do I find the numeric value of my category? it dosnt have one does it?

Comment: Edit you category and when edit page opens, look for `tag_ID` value in the address bar of your browser. This value of `tag_ID` is actually the ID of the category you are editing.

Comment: @stack go into wordpress admin, go to posts>categories, and click on the category you are interested in. The url in your browser will then show something ending like this: `category&tag_ID=1&post_type=post` the number after `tag-ID=` is your category id

Comment: So mine says tag_ID=26 shall I replace nn with that?

Comment: I have done that, but it still show the posts form other categories?

Comment: Please ensure this category is applied to appropriate posts and not all.

Comment: Just checked and the category is not associated to any other, I have this category and two other and they are not linked.

Comment: It is on the main index.php of the template yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58420/discussion-between-ghazanfar-mir-and-stack).

Comment: I have tried to show these specific category posts but still nothing is working :(

Comment: Can you check if the `index.php` template is been used? may be it is using different template?

Comment: How do I check to see if that is being used? Im sure it is.

Comment: echo something on the template.. or put `echo "Im been used";` after `wp_reset_query();`